# How to get my code to print out the following example

Tags: java

im doing a java project and i ran into a problem with it. Im trying to work out why its not calculating the total price on the items as you can see in te output that no total price is displayed.

I get the following output (FYI TEST CASE FIVE IS SUPPOSED TO BE LIKE THAT)

```
Test Case 1: 
ProductName:  
ProductPrice: 0.0
Order Quantity: 0
Total price: 0.0
Test Case 2: 
ProductName: Pens 
ProductPrice: 0.6
Order Quantity: 50
Total price: 0.0
Test Case 3: 
ProductName: Pencil's 
ProductPrice: 0.3
Order Quantity: 115
Total price: 0.0
Test Case 4: 
ProductName: Rulers 
ProductPrice: 1.2
Order Quantity: 4
Total price: 0.0
Test Case 5: 
ERROR: the discount value:115.0 is not valid
```

My code:

```
public class Order {
String ProductName;
double Price;
double Discount;
int Quantity;
double Total;
String Message; // intallising them as var 

boolean isDiscounted = false; //declaring the var also to false
boolean isValidOrder = true;

public static int OrderNum = 0; //static var  

public Order() {        // constructor #!
    isValidOrder= false;
    Message = "Error: You have not specified any parameters for the order";
    OrderNum++;
}
public Order(String ProductName, double Price, int Quantity){
     //calling from parameter 
    this.ProductName = ProductName;
    this.Quantity = Quantity; //receving the three parameters 
    this.Price = Price;
    OrderNum++;
}

public Order(String ProductName, double Price, int Quantity, double Discount){
    this.ProductName = ProductName;
    this.Price = Price;
    this.Quantity = Quantity;
    this.Discount = Discount;
    OrderNum++;

    if (Discount < 100){  // Will run if the Discount is < 100

         this.Discount = Discount;//assigning this to discount parameter to its instance variable 
        isDiscounted = true;
    }
    else {
        isValidOrder = false;

        Message = "ERROR: the discount value:"+ Discount +" is not valid";}

    }

    public void calculate(){
        if (isValidOrder=true){ //if its a vaild order
            System.out.println(Total = Quantity * Price);

        }
        else{ //if not valid order this will run 
            Message = "Error:order number: "+OrderNum + "cannot be totalled as it is invaild";
            isDiscounted = false; 
        }


        if (isDiscounted = true){ // runs if order is discounted
            System.out.println(Total = Quantity * Price - Quantity * Price * (Discount/100));
        }
         /*else{ //if not  discounted then this will run
            System.out.print(Total= Quantity * Price); */
        }


        public String toString(){
        if (isValidOrder){
                Message =  "ProductName: " + ProductName +"\n" +  "ProductPrice: " + Price +"\n"+  "Order Quantity: " + Quantity  +
                        "\n" +  "Total price: " + Total; 


                    //if the order is valid and not discounted
        }

        else if (isDiscounted ){

            Message = "Product Name: " + ProductName + "\n " + "Product Price:  $" + Price + "\n"+ "Order Quanity:" + Quantity + "\n " +
            "Discount: " + Discount + "%" + "\n" + "Total Price: $" + Total;
                // if the item is discounted 
        }
        return Message;


        }}





public class OrderCreator {


public static void main(String[] args){
    Order o1 = new Order (" ",0, 0);
    System.out.println("Test Case 1: " + "\n" + o1); //test case one

Order o2 = new Order ( "Pens ",0.60, 50 );
System.out.println("Test Case 2: " + "\n" + o2);

Order o3 = new Order ( "Pencil's ",0.30, 115, 0 );
System.out.println("Test Case 3: " + "\n" + o3);

Order o4 = new Order ( "Rulers ",1.20, 4, 15 ); //15% discount on this one
System.out.println("Test Case 4: " + "\n" + o4);

Order o5 = new Order ( "Pencil Sharpners ",2.05, 8,115 ); //should come up as error due to only 100%, 115% discount
System.out.println("Test Case 5: " + "\n" + o5);

}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the main?

Comment: The `else` that calculates a non-discounted total is commented out, so the total is always zero since you don't have any discounted test inputs.

Comment: Just added the main.

Comment: I just uncommented the "else". Still coming up with the same result

Comment: `isValidOrder` is never initialised in a non discounted flow. Moreover, test case 5 is not discounted per the constructor used.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to run calculate() method in two of the constructors in Order class

```
public Order(String ProductName, double Price, int Quantity){
     //calling from parameter 
    this.ProductName = ProductName;
    this.Quantity = Quantity; //receving the three parameters 
    this.Price = Price;
    OrderNum++;
    this.calculate();
}

public Order(String ProductName, double Price, int Quantity, double Discount){
    this.ProductName = ProductName;
    this.Price = Price;
    this.Quantity = Quantity;
    this.Discount = Discount;
    OrderNum++;

    if (Discount < 100){  // Will run if the Discount is < 100

         this.Discount = Discount;//assigning this to discount parameter to its instance variable 
        isDiscounted = true;
    }
    else {
        isValidOrder = false;

        Message = "ERROR: the discount value:"+ Discount +" is not valid";

    }
    this.calculate();
}
```

Also remove System.out.println from calculate class as it doesnt output in a nice format otherwise. toString method will do all the system.out.println

```
public void calculate(){
if (isValidOrder){ //if its a vaild order
    Total = Quantity * Price; 

}
else{ //if not valid order this will run 
    Message = "Error: order number: "+OrderNum + " cannot be totalled as it is invaild";
    isDiscounted = false; 
}


if (isDiscounted){ // runs if order is discounted
    Total = Quantity * Price - Quantity * Price * (Discount/100); 


}
 /*else{ //if not  discounted then this will run
    Total= Quantity * Price; */
}
```